# Set timeout Function on inactivity of user in React JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, authentication

I have created login form in reactjs. This stores a token in state. Login and Logout functions are working properly. But I want to expire this token on inactivity of the user and user will automatically logout.

Login:

```
export const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        
        setLogin: (state, action) => {
            state.user = action.payload.user;
            state.token = action.payload.token;
        },
        setLogout: (state) => {
            state.user = null;
            state.token = null;
        }
    },
});

const login = async (values, onSubmitProps) => {
    const loggedInResponse = await fetch("http://localhost:5001/auth/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(values),
    });
    const loggedIn = await loggedInResponse.json();
    
    onSubmitProps.resetForm();
    if (loggedIn) {
      dispatch(
        setLogin({
          user: loggedIn.user,
          token: loggedIn.token,
        })
      );
      navigate("/dashboard");
    }
  };

const handleFormSubmit = async (values, onSubmitProps) => {
    if (isLogin) await login(values, onSubmitProps);
  };
```